# My radio buttons are not allowing me to select more than one on the full page

Tags: php, html, forms, session, radio-button

Is there any way to alter this code to allow one radio button to be pressed per section/loop:

```
<form action="Mark.php" method="POST">
<?php
for($x = 0; $x <= $_SESSION["numofquestions"]-1; $x++) {
    echo '<fieldset class="QuestionField" style="border-radius:20%;border-color:PowderBlue">
        <legend>Question '.($x+1).': '.$Question[$x].'</legend>
        '.$Answer1[$x].'<input type="radio" name="q1_answer" value="1">
        <br>
        '.$Answer2[$x].'<input type="radio" name="q1_answer" value="2">
        <br>';
    if(!empty($Answer3[$x])) {
        echo $Answer3[$x].'<input type="radio" name="q1_answer" value="3">
        <br>';
    }
    if(!empty($Answer4[$x])) {
        echo $Answer4[$x].'<input type="radio" name="q1_answer" value="4">
        <br>';
    }
    echo '</fieldset><br>';
}
?>
<button type="submit" class="niceButton">Check Answers</button>
</form>
```

Comment: to work radio button in group, you should have a different name for each of the radio button groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this I made small modifications in your code. Each radio button name will be dynamic according to the questions.

```
<form action="Mark.php" method="POST">
<?php
for($x = 0; $x <= $_SESSION["numofquestions"]-1; $x++) {
    $questionNumber = $x+1;
?>
    <fieldset class="QuestionField" style="border-radius:20%;border-color:PowderBlue">
        <legend>Question <?php echo $questionNumber; ?>: <?php echo $Question[$x]; ?></legend>
        <?php echo $Answer1[$x]; ?> <input type="radio" name="q<?php echo $questionNumber; ?>_answer" value="1"><br>
        <?php echo $Answer2[$x]; ?> <input type="radio" name="q<?php echo $questionNumber; ?>_answer" value="2"><br>
        <?php
        if(!empty($Answer3[$x])) {
        ?>
            <?php echo $Answer3[$x]; ?> <input type="radio" name="q<?php echo $questionNumber; ?>_answer" value="3"><br>
        }
        if(!empty($Answer4[$x])) {
        ?>
            <?php echo $Answer4[$x]; ?> <input type="radio" name="q<?php echo $questionNumber; ?>_answer" value="4"><br>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </fieldset><br>
<?php
}
?>
<button type="submit" class="niceButton">Check Answers</button>
</form>
```